# What are the solutions to $ac+bd=1$, for $a$ and $b$, where $a,b,c,d$ are integers and $c$ and $d$ have HCF $1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What are the solutions to $ac+bd=1$, for $a$ and $b$, where $a,b,c,d$ are integers, and $c$ and $d$ have HCF $1$?
A few examples:
Give all the solutions for $a$ and $b$ for the following:

$$3a+5b=1 \\
3a+7b=1 \\
4a+5b=1$$

General case:
$ac+bd=1$

I was able to do the above to provide a general formula in terms of $a$ and $b$ in terms of $n$, where $n\in \{1,2,3\ldots \}$ for the first $3$ but struggled with the general case.

I'm presuming there's some sort of way to get $a$ and $b$ in terms of $c$ and $d$, but I'm not sure.

Cheers.

Comment: This can help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#One_equation

Comment: Given two integers $c,d$, you can compute their gcd using [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). As a by-product of the algorithm, you will find a pair of $a,b$ such that $\gcd(c,d) = ac+bd$.

Answer (score 1):

By the identity of Bezout, (*others call it a lemma and even a theorem;French use identity*) if $(c,d)=m$ then
$a\mathbb Z+b\mathbb Z= m\mathbb Z$ so in the case of $m=1$ you do have $a\mathbb Z+b\mathbb Z= \mathbb Z$. There are infinitely many solutions.